# Modify the remember me for fosuserbundle to different routes depending the role

Tags: php, symfony

I am using FOSUserBundle and `remember me`. I have a section where normal `ROLE_USER` users get redirected to after login, but I also have an admin section for `ROLE_ADMIN` users. The `remember me` function works perfect for normal users. But for `ROLE_ADMIN` users the location after a `remember me` is the same location for normal users. The admin can access the same homepage the normal users access after login.

But how can I modify the `remember me` so that normal users go to the normal homepage like it already do, and that `ROLE_ADMIN` users go to the admin homepage (or dashboard) after a `remember me`?

This is my security.yml;

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                success_handler:     login_success_handler
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 31536000
                path:     /
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    access_denied_url: /
```

For what it's worth.

Comment: You forgot to post the code I guess.

Comment: I've added my `security.yml` for what it's worth. Can't see any purpose. I just want to know whether there are a property or way to make the remember me path different for different roles.

Comment: you can create two firewall one for admin admin_secured_area without remember me option and one for member_secured_area for users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create multiple firewall:

```
firewalls:
        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: /admin/.*
            provider: entity_admin
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/
        members_secured_area:
            pattern: /members/.*
```

Comment: Do we need to repeat `form_login:` or `logout:` configurations in the second firewall?

Comment: Ahh! How come I haven't thought of that? Thank you!